# Sailsjs "required" Model Attribute in the default JSON API

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Should SailsJS be throwing an HTTP error if a "required" model attribute is not passed into the automatically generated JSON API?

Or is this logic I must implement myself in the Controller?

Answer (score 2):

Pat, what version are you on?

In 0.9, you should get an error response in this case.